# Adjusting QSqlTableModel for a QTreeView

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, treeview, qsqltablemodel

I'm trying to put a MySQL table into a `treeView`.

Each entry has three values in the database - `id`, `text`, `parentId`. 
This `treeView` needs to be editable so I really like the `QSqlTableModel` approach, as the functionality to save back to database is already built in.

Now, the `treeView` is showing all entries in the same line, of course, and I need a hierarchy. What would be the best way to build this hierarchy, while maintaining the editing and saving capabilities?
(I'm using MySQL.)

**mainwindow.h**

`private: QSqlTableModel* goalModel;`

**mainwindow.cpp**

*(this makes a flat table hierarchy. the table is filtered based on which entry is clicked in another table)*

```
void MainWindow::on_tableViewGoals_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{   
    goalModel = new QSqlTableModel(this);
    goalModel->setTable("goals");

    //Gets the id from the clicked entry to use as filter
    QString idGoals = index.sibling(row,0).data().toString();
    goalModel->setFilter( "id_goals=" + idGoals );

    goalModel->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnRowChange);
    goalModel->select();

    ui->treeView->setModel(goalModel);
    ...
```

I tried this. It's wrong, but I don't really know why. *(the third column contains the parentId value, if the entry has it)*

```
for (int row = 0; row < goalModel->rowCount(); ++row)
{
    //if the entry has a value over 0 in the parentId column
    if (goalModel->index(row,2).data().toInt() > 0)
    {
        //get number in column 2
        int parentId;
        parentId = goalModel->index(row,2).data().toInt();
        QModelIndex newChild = goalModel->index(row,0);
        //find QModelIndex row with matching number in column 0
        for (int row = 0; row < goalModel->rowCount(); ++row)
        {
            if (goalModel->index(row,0).data().toInt() == parentId )
            {
               //make this entry that entry's child
               QModelIndex newParent = goalModel->index(row,0);
               newChild = goalModel->index(0,0,newParent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All indexes are already made, so no need to make new ones, just assign a parent to all those who have one. How best to do that?

Comment: You want to implement a view model - a proxy between the source table model and the view.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean a `QSortFilterProxyModel`? I guess I would need to reimplement `mapToSource()` and `mapFromSource()`. Would that keep the editing and saving capabilities that `QSqlTableModel` gives me?